# Proper way to handle three completely different layouts in AngularJS &UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What is the proper way to switch between three completely different layouts using AngularJS?  Route variables?  Populating the root scope?  Nested controllers?  Some magical method of maintaining the variables after causing the browser to navigate to a different URL without routing?  I'm using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

> NOTE: 
>   I am leaning towards using nested controllers however I'm stumped as how to target a specific UIView.  For example, if a nest a view for a side-nav area, how can an sref (or similar), from the side-nave, change the main-body area?

My client handed me a static version of their site with 100 useful page samples, however the overall layout of many pages is drastically different.  They all have data elements that would all tie together:

**Semi-Public Area (approx 15 pages)**
Similar to a public marketting web site but with a title bar, showing notifications for the user IF they are logged in.

**Dashboard (approx 45 pages)**
Complex pages for use in a web-based admin application.

**User Application (approx 40 pages)**
The actual public application.  Changes made in the Dashboard must show in real time during this same session.

Comment: These sound like standard templates, I could be wrong though as you do not mention if these are shown all together or if the user switches between these areas.

Comment: You should read up on the idea of nested states / views:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: @Enzey Users may switch between them.  For example, if a general user reads the Contact Us page, in the Public area, the navbar at the top shows their current username, stats, and links to return to the public application.  Likewise, an administrator is able to bounce between all three without having to log in/out.

Comment: Probably should be three separate apps, or sub apps within the same overall application. Each having its own landing page. Code reuse should still be achieved using modules shared in all three. A session token can be employed to share Auth between apps. Otherwise, uirouter is your best bet.